# Хранилища больших объемов данных. В какую сторону смотреть?

Tags: база-данных, redis

Направленность проекта предполагает хранение большого объема строковых данных (несколько миллионов строк). К тому же, будут регулярные запросы на обновление \ чтение какого-то количества строк из базы. Простой mysql этого, явно, не вытянет, и встал вопрос, как бы это дело оптимизировать, в сторону какого продукта глянуть.

Самым адекватным выходом вижу использование Reddis + кеширование некоторого объема данных, которые будут использоваться чаще всего.

Но всё же хотелось бы знать и чужое мнение в этом плане, кто бы и что мог посоветовать, как грамотнее организовать структуру таблиц.

С такими большими объемами данных и такой частотностью их использования еще не сталкивался, поэтому пришел за советом сюда.

Comment: Любой простой mysql вытянет миллионы строк без проблем

Comment: @etki, оно и понятно, но скорость поиска строк может в разы упасть, что в этом случае будет очень большой проблемой. 
И как-то хочется заранее все это обойти, что бы потом не мучиться в истерике исправляя положение

Comment: Скорость поиска можно ускорить с помощью индексов, ценой некоторого замедления при записи и дополнительных расходов дискового места и оперативки. Даже при всей своей нелюбви к MySQL я не вижу здесь ни одной конкретной причины, мешающей выбрать его.

Comment: а вариант кластера вы не рассматриваете?

Comment: С чего бы ей в разы падать? Индексы-то как правило из деревьев делаются, там логарифмическая зависимость. Само требование "миллионы строк" никак не исключает мускул из гонки.

Answer (score 0):

Какой размер БД вы считаете будет? Если это в пределах десятков гигабайт, то MySQL без особенных проблем его потянет. На сервере с близким к объему данных объемом оперативки это даже будет быстро. И на менее мощном сервере оно будет работать.

Если вы рассматриваете Redis и думаете что сможете использовать его для хранения больших объемов данных на маломощном сервере, то забудьте об этом. Для Redis нужно [чтобы все ключи помещались в ОЗУ](https://redis.io/topics/virtual-memory). Значит в случае с Redis вам не обойтись без мощного сервера. В случае с MySQL все не так строго.

Comment: Серверные мощности роли существенной не играют, проблем с ними нет. 
Главная задача - выиграть скорость.

Comment: Размер БД на данный момент и не подсчитаешь. Специфика такая, что она будет постоянно расти.

Comment: Какой сервер вы хотите брать с самого начала?